# Tkinter Toplevel in OOP script: how?

Tags: python, tkinter, window, toplevel

**Goal of the script:**

- (3) different windows, each in its own class, with its own widgets and layout, are created via Toplevel and callbacks.
- When a new (Toplevel) window is created, the previous one is destroyed. Thus, only one window is visible and active at a time.

**Problem?**
Basically, I've tried many things and failed, so I must understand too little of `["parent", "master", "root", "app", "..."]` :(

**Note on raising windows:**
I have implemented a successful example of loading all frames on top of each other, and controlling their visibility via the `.raise` method.

For this problem, however, I don't want to load all the frames at once.
This is an abstracted version of a quiz program that will require quite a lot of frames with images, which makes me reluctant to load everything at once.

**Script** ***(not working; bugged):***

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox, tkFont, random, ttk

class First_Window(Frame):
    """The option menu which is shown at startup"""
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.gotosecond = Button(text = "Start", command = self.goto_Second)
        self.gotosecond.grid(row = 2, column = 3, sticky = W+E)

    def goto_Second(self):
        self.master.withdraw()
        self.master.update_idletasks()
        Second_Window = Toplevel(self)

class Second_Window(Toplevel):
    """The gamewindow with questions, timer and entrywidget"""
    def __init__(self, *args):
        Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.focus_set()

        self.gotothird = Button(text = "gameover", command = self.goto_Third)
        self.gotothird.grid(row = 2, column = 3, sticky = W+E)

    def goto_Third(self):
        Third_Window = Toplevel(self)
        self.destroy()

class Third_Window(Toplevel):
    """Highscores are shown with buttons to Startmenu"""
    def __init__(self, *args):
        Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.focus_set()
        self.master = First_Window

        self.gotofirst = Button(text = "startover", command = self.goto_First)
        self.gotofirst.grid(row = 2, column = 3, sticky = W+E)

    def goto_First(self):
        self.master.update()
        self.master.deiconify()
        self.destroy()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Algebra game by PJK")
    app = First_Window(root)
    root.resizable(FALSE,FALSE)
    app.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: With this script, the First Screen loads just fine. Clicking on the button (goto_Second) will open up a new window that displays nothing. Closing that window also doesn't seem to close the program (as I have to close the terminal window too).

Comment: You could use `self.top = Toplevel(self)` inside your `First_Window` class, then just do `self.top.destroy()` whenever creating a new window.  For the widgets that will be present in the Toplevel window you can do `self.some_button = Button(self.top, text='Start', command=self.goto_Second)` so that the widget uses `self.top` as the parent.

Comment: Please don't edit your question into a completely different question using the code from the answers. That makes the answers wrong, and the question useless for anyone who had the same problem as you. If your followup is too major to explain in a comment or an addendum edited onto the end of your question, create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not really a Tkinter problem, but a basic problem with classes vs. instances. Actually, two similar but separate problems. You probably need to read through a tutorial on classes, like [the one in the official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

---

First:

```
self.master = First_Window
```

`First_Window` is a class. You have an *instance* of that class (in the global variable named `app`), which represents the first window on the screen. You can call `update` and `deiconify` and so forth on that instance, because it represents that window. But `First_Window` itself isn't representing any particular window, it's just a class, a factory for *creating* instances that represent particular windows. So you can't call `update` or `deiconify` on the class.

What you probably want to do is pass the first window down through the chain of windows. (You could, alternatively, access the global, or do various other things, but this seems cleanest.) You're already trying to pass it to `Second_Window`, you just need to stash it and pass it again in the `Second_Window` (instead of passing `self` instance, which is useless—it's just a destroyed window object), and then stash it and use it in the `Third_Window`.

---

Second:

```
Second_Window = Toplevel(self)
```

Instead of creating an instance of the `Second_Window` class, you're just creating an instance of the generic `Toplevel` class, and giving it the local name `Second_Window` (which temporarily hides the class name… but since you never use that class, that doesn't really matter).

And you have the same problem when you try to create the third window.

---

So:

```
class First_Window(Frame):
    # ...
    def goto_Second(self):
        # ...
        second = Second_Window(self)

class Second_Window(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, first, *args):
        Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.first = first
        # ...

    def goto_Third(self):
        third = Third_Window(self.first)
        self.destroy()

class Third_Window(Toplevel):
    """Highscores are shown with buttons to Startmenu"""
    def __init__(self, first, *args):
        Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.first = first
        # ...

    def goto_First(self):
        self.first.update()
        self.first.deiconify()
        self.destroy()
```

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question with where I'm at so far.
Going from one window to the next seems to be working just fine.
Destroying them, however, does not!?

Also note that I've switched to using Frame. Toplevel worked like this as well and showed the same results.

Comment: Destroying a `Frame` doesn't destroy the window the frame is in; it only destroys the frame itself and all of its contents, generally leaving you an empty grey window.